# Searching JSON file objects with Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

i need some help being able to populate data on my page based on "vilcode" in my json file. I am currently able to pull the data using the main object name "demo1", "demo2", "demo3" but i need to be able to get the same data by matching the vilcode.

Basically i can populate the page using the parent object, but i need to be able to populate rihgt data based on child objects. Thoughts? Thank you for your help

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('mydata.json', function (jd) {
        $('#contact-info').html(jd[$url].ADDRESS);
    });
```

JSON file look like this:

```
{
    "demo1": {
        "CLIENT": "demo1",
        "VILCODE": "1A",
        "ADDRESS": "101 Demo Street"
    },
    "demo2": {
        "CLIENT": "demo2",
        "VILCODE": "2A",
        "ADDRESS": "101 Demo Street"
    },
    "demo3": {
            "CLIENT": "demo3",
            "VILCODE": "3A",
            "ADDRESS": "101 Demo Street"
        },
```

Comment: they were all in same format, i just messed up in the post, trying to make the variables more simple.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple method would be to use a [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop such as:

```
for(var demoName in data)
{
    if(data[demoName].VILCODE == "3A")
    {
        alert("found demo with VILCODE=3A named: "+demoName);
    }
}
```

Sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9vrey0kb/) which assumed that your demo3 has same format as rest.

Comment: Thanks so much Mike! You are the man!! God bless you dude,saved me hours :)